# Unable to start a Service from jobScheduler

Tags: android, service, android-jobscheduler

I am trying to start a service from jobScheduler.

```
public class Scheduler extends JobService {

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "JobService is running!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent service = new Intent(this, LocationActivity.class);
    this.startService(service);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return false;
}

}
```

LocationActivity is my service which is not getting called. 
I have added in manifest file as well.

Please do let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You have class called `xxxActivity`, but it's a `Service`?

Comment: LocationActivity is your service?

Comment: Yes! LocationActivity is my service.

Comment: I think there must be some issues in that service itself. Id it possible to show your service and how you have added it to manifest here.